# Which project should I enable migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-migrations

I have a wpf project, with the structure below:

```
project1(solution)
|->Model(project)
|->DataAccess(project)
|->project1(project)
```

Project1 is the project where I compile and deliver the exe to the user.

Now I want to enable automatic migration: `Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations`

project1 is the default project. When I run the command, obviously it won't be able to find the database context, which is located in the `DataAccess` project. I am able to enable it in the `DataAccess` project.

But is it correct? How can I enable it in the project1 project?

---

EDITED:

I think I can enable migration in the `DataAccess` project, and have it MyConfiguration reference back to `DataAccess` project?

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, MyConfiguration>());
```

But I get this error:

```
Error   2   'DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried using the -StartupProjectName parameter?

`Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -ProjectName DataAccess -StartupProjectName project1`

The last parameter specifies to emulate running within that project, including any settings from app.config/web.config.

Edit: as for enabling migrations, the error you're seeing is probably because the MigrationsConfiguration is created by default as internal.  You can either:

- Make it public
- Set the DB initializer somewhere in the DataAccess project
- Set it in the app.config/web.config for project1.  Even though the type is internal, it will resolve at runtime and still work:

  ```
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="DataAccess.FooContext, DataAccess">
        <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[DataAccess.FooContext, DataAccess], [DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration, DataAccess]], EntityFramework, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        </databaseInitializer>
      </context>
    </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
  ```

Comment: This worked for me, I had two projects on one solution and from this I used `Enable-Migrations -ProjectName ProjectNameGoesHere -StartupProjectName StartupProjectNameGoesHere -ContextTypeName ContextNameToAddMigrationsGoesHere` to enable migrations  for the second project on the solution.